# How to extend class for list.phtml

Tags: magento2, list.phtml

can anyone tell me, which class I  have to extend if I want to use custom functions in list.phtml?

Thx, Christian

Answer (score 0):

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" name="category.products.list" as="product_list" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list.phtml">
```

So you have to rewrite : `Magento/Catalog/Block/Product/ListProduct.php`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference type="Vender\Module-name\Block\Product\ListProduct"  for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct"/>
</config>
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try

Comment: Hi, can you explain more please?? Where I have to put the new ListProduct.php,and how to refer? For me it is the first time that I try to overide a class, therefore I don't know how and where. Sorry

Comment: Please check this : https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/279201/48355

Comment: Thank you, I just solved it by using Helper-Classes