# Magento 2 : Trying to Override ListProduct.php Block File for Custom Product Collection

Tags: magento2, product-collection

I am trying to override *ListProduct.php* **Block** File Using **Preference method** But *InitialiseProductCollection()* being a protected function does not give me result. I need to know how can I override a protected function of *ListProduct.php*

Answer (score 0):

You can check the solution of your problem here:[Magento 2 Override ListProduct.php Block File](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/279196/magento-2-override-listproduct-php-block-file).

Let's us know if solution help you