# Magento 2.4: Which event triggers when the category page is loaded in magento2?

Tags: magento2, category, event-observer, plugin

I want to know which event is triggered when a category page is loaded from the megamenu?
I want to load a custom collection of data based on a particular category.

Comment: what do you mean by "a category page is loaded from the megamenu?"

Comment: @Marius It is when we click on a category link on the mega menu and that category page loads.

Comment: try to use `catalog_controller_category_init_after` but this is triggered for any category view. it does not matter if you click on it from the menu or from somewhere else

Comment: Are you looking for custom collection for specific category?

Comment: Thanks @Marius your solution worked.

Answer (score 0):

In **module-catalog** you will find all the events related to the category, in **etc/events.xml** file you will find all the events.
i guess this is your event.

```
<event name="magento_catalog_api_data_categoryinterface_load_after">
        <observer name="legacy_category_load_after" instance="Magento\Framework\EntityManager\Observer\AfterEntityLoad" />
</event>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can update category's product collection by override Product Block.

Override your list block and apply condition in `initializeProductCollection`

```
\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct::initializeProductCollection
```

Reference : [Magento 2 Override ListProduct.php Block File](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/279196/magento-2-override-listproduct-php-block-file)

Also Magento provide event for product collection `catalog_product_collection_load_after`

check _afterLoad function in
https://github.com/pepe1518/magento2/blob/master/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Product/Collection.php